# Gráfico coluna 3D Highcharts com aparência do Amcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Como posso personalizar o highcharts para que fique sem a rotação do gráfico em sim, igual ao Amcharts? 
As tentativas que fiz foi mudando as configurações

```
 alpha: 15,
 beta: 15,
 depth: 50,
 viewDistance: 25
```

e as configurações do amcharts:

```
"depth3D": 20,
"angle": 30,
```

mas não obtive nenhum resultado parecido.

Highcharts 3D Column:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Amcharts 3D Column:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue as configurações de rotação dos ângulos.

```
alpha: 0,
beta: 0,
depth: 20,
```

Para mais configurações de ângulos [aqui](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.options3d) na seção  `chart.options3d`

```js
$('#grafico').highcharts({
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    options3d: {
      enabled: true,
      alpha: 0,
      beta: 0,
      depth: 20,
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [4500, 2000, 1500, 1300, 1000, 900, 800, 700, 600, 500, 400, 300]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>

<div id="grafico"></div>
```